# Is there a way to restore ubuntu 12.10 to default.

Tags: restore

I want to remove everything from the hard drive and restore ubuntu 12.10, can someone please help?

Comment: So you want to reinstall?

Comment: Only Windows 8 supports this, as far as I know. This "restore" thing. I guess distributions including Ubuntu will include the feature somewhat later on. (But for now, check Ads2000's answer.)

Answer (score 4):

The way to do that is just to reinstall.
I would recommend installing 13.04 considering that comes out today and if you want longer support, grab 12.04.2 LTS not 12.10.